# Change value of public property on click of button (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, properties

I have a Windows Form that contains a check box list and a button. I also have another class where I want to receive variables from this winform. So what I'm trying to do as a test is to click the button in my winform and have the other class to pop up a MessageBox.
This is the what I wrote for the winform:
**WINFORM**

```
    private DialogResult DR;

    public DialogResult DiaRes
    {
        get { return DR; }
        set { }
    }

    public SelectLinksM(string[] allLinks)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(allLinks);
        checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
    }

    public void sndLinksSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DR = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

And this is what happens in the other class:
**EXTERNAL CLASS**

```
        MyClass.SelectLinksM frmSelection =
        new MyClass.SelectLinksM(linkNames.ToArray());
        frmSelection.Show();

        DialogResult result = frmSelection.DiaRes;

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I passed a value to the main class!");
        }
```

But right now clicking on the button doesn't do anything.
What I am expecting is to click on the button so that it changes the value of DR, consequently DiaRes, that gets read by the other class and this triggers the MessageBox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing in your other class to check whether the value of DR has changed, so your handling code is never called.  Look in to raising an event on the change, perhaps INotifyPropertyChanged could be useful for you, or you can just add your own `public event EventHandler DRChanged`

Comment: Little confusion: the text says you have a form and a class, and you want the class to get variables from the form.  But the code shows a class sending data to the form..  frmSelection surely is the form, you wanna show that modally not just show it.

Comment: I know decoupling is a thing, but this takes it to the extreme. there is no reference or segway to your other class at all. it just sits there like i do at work, doing nothing

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish here ? Your code does not seem to have anything to do with the text of your question

Comment: @BugFinder yes it works in both ways: first I send a list of strings to the form to populate the check box list, then I want to send back the info that I pressed the Ok button and so I want the other class to pop a messagebox.
LordWilmore You mean that in the other class I have to put something that checks if I changed the value of DR?
(Sorry guys I'm a designer, I'm fairly new to programming)

Comment: So your class has to populate the Form with values, and a click on a button on the form has to trigger a response in that same class again, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @GuidoG I'm trying to write something that allows me to click the button in the form and this will trigger _MessageBox.Show("I passed a value to the main class!");_ in the other external class. So in this way I'll understand how to bring across other things (my end goal will be to send to the other class the indices of what has been selected by the user from the check box list.

Comment: @GuidoG Yes so the class has to populate the Form with values, and a click on a button on the form has to pop up the messagebox in the first class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on writing custom classes and subclassing.
Let my try to show a simple example here

First a simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private _dialogResult DialogResult;

    public DialogResult MyDialogResult
    {
       get { return _dialogResult; }
       set 
       {
          _diaologResult = value;
          ShowYourMessage();
       }
    }

    private void ShowYourMessage()
    {
       MessageBox.Show("I passed a value to the main class!");
    }
}
```

now in your winform

```
private _myClass MyClass = new MyClass();
```

and inside a click event

```
_myClass.MyDialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Inside MyClass you can create frmMessage to your liking, I have used an empty form here just to show how it works

This way, you can have all code in your winform to an absolute minimum and keep all code in your class for good sepearation and decoupling

Comment: No problem, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

**Description** 
You do not trigger the method you want. By clicking, you execute the `sndLinksSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, but in that method, you only change a value but do not dispatch another action. You should call that method in the seperate class. I made an example of what I mean, you should edit it to your needs

**Example**

```
  private DialogResult DR;

    public DialogResult DiaRes
    {
        get { return DR; }
        set { }
    }

    public SelectLinksM(string[] allLinks)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(allLinks);
        checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
    }

    public void sndLinksSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DR = DialogResult.OK;
        //<!---- Trigger the action here or nothing will happen
        DoSomething();
    }


public void DoSomething(){
        MyClass.SelectLinksM frmSelection = new MyClass.SelectLinksM(linkNames.ToArray());
        frmSelection.Show();

        DialogResult result = frmSelection.DiaRes;

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I passed a value to the main class!");
        }
}
```

Comment: You mean to create the changeTextBox method within the form class? cause what I'm trying to do is not to pop up the messagebox from there but from the main class...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It make more sense now but I'm not really sure it is correct:
What is in the method DoSomething() comes from the other class that is not inside the same class file (in Visual Studio I mean) so, for example, I can't use the variable linkNames, because it's not here. I tried to clarify a bit more in my question above.

Comment: in this solution it is the WinForm that has to trigger the message itself, not your class. Check my answer, there the class will trigger the messagebox and the WinForm only sets a property value